# How do I read a file created in Unix into R on a Windows 10 computer?

Tags: r, file-conversion

I downloaded and unzipped a file from the web that was created on a Unix system. I need it read into a tibble in R, with the correct variable names.

```
UKBPP_outcome <- read_tsv ("3_UK_Biobank_parental_17May2018")
```

This gives me a file with ONE variable, 7 million records. All of the fields I am interested in are strung together, separated by spaces. There are in fact 9 variables in this file, not one.

```
UKBPP_outcome <- read_tsv ("3_UK_Biobank_parental_17May2018")
```

The file is at http://www.ccace.ed.ac.uk/node/335
under the rubric Marioni_Alzheimer's_disease_TP_208.zip
Warning: it is over 7,000,000 records.

I want a tibble with 9 variable columns. Instead, I get one variable like this:

```
SNP A1 A2 BETA SE P DIR CHR BP                          
  <chr>                                                     
1 1:101166253_TG_T T TG -0.0076 0.0114 0.5036 -+ 1 101166253
```

Comment: Perhaps the columns are space-delimited, not tab? In which case try `read_table`. It would also help to provide a smaller sample of the file or its contents; no-one will download 700+ MB to answer a question :)

Comment: Most data is distributed as csv or fwf. Why are you assuming tsv?

Comment: You could always try `data.table::fread()` which has the added bonus of auto-detecting the delimiters and `colClasses`. It won't work if the file is a fixed width file.

Comment: Deleted OS tags which had nothing to do with the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`'s `fread` function is perfect for this, especially given the size of the data.

If we download the file in question, we can first unzip it in R, then read it in, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

file <- unzip("./UKB_AD_sumstats_17May2018.zip")

f1 <- fread(file[2])

                      SNP A1 A2    BETA     SE       P DIR CHR        BP
      1: 1:101166253_TG_T  T TG -0.0076 0.0114 0.50360  -+   1 101166253
      2:  1:102884223_A_G  A  G -0.0037 0.0102 0.71920  --   1 102884223
      3:  1:105351556_C_T  T  C -0.0034 0.0099 0.72850  -+   1 105351556
      4:  1:105412363_T_C  T  C  0.0115 0.0105 0.27400  +-   1 105412363
      5:  1:105413338_A_G  A  G  0.0083 0.0099 0.40350  ++   1 105413338
     ---                                                                
7795601:        rs9999993  A  T  0.0050 0.0100 0.62050  ++   4  98562671
7795602:        rs9999995  A  G -0.0012 0.0102 0.90980  -+   4 185171608
7795603:        rs9999996  A  C -0.0257 0.0104 0.01376  --   4  69782467
7795604:        rs9999997  A  G -0.0057 0.0100 0.56740  +-   4 163870478
7795605:        rs9999998  T  C -0.0004 0.0102 0.96540  -+   4 117161848
```

If we run `fread` with `verbose = TRUE`, we see that:

```
Detecting sep automatically ...
  sep=' '  with 100 lines of 9 fields using quote rule 0
```

So the file in question is space delimited.

I also ran a benchmark out of curiosity to see how much better `fread` handled the data size. I first attempted running `read.table` without specifying `colClasses`, and after several minutes of watching my mouse wheel spin, I gave up. I went back and added `skip = 1`, and the `colClasses` vector:

```
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark( "fread" = { f1 <- fread(file)},
 "read.table" = { f2 <- read.table(file, sep = " ", colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "character", "integer", "integer"), skip = 1)},
replications =1)

         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1      fread            1    2.04    1.000      3.64     0.18         NA        NA
2 read.table            1   17.20    8.431     16.03     1.13         NA        NA
```

For this data set, `fread` is about 8x faster that `read.table`.